# Accurately measuring execution time in seconds

Tags: c, time

I wanted to know the execution time of a program, but I also wanted to exclude the time needed for file input/output. For this purpose I used the `time()` function.  There are many `.h` and `.cpp` files but here are the only places where time objects are referenced.

My problem is, while start's value is set correctly at the beginning it loses it (is set to zero) when `dosomethingelse()` is invoked for the first time. This makes `sub_duration` to have a very big value because now the difference between `end` and `start` , which is zero, is the value of `end`.

Here is how I used it:

main.cpp

```
time_t start=0;
time_t end=0;
time_t sub_duration=0;
time_t total_duration=0; 

int main()
{
    start = time(NULL);
    while(somethingtodo)
    {
        dosomething();
        dosomethingelse();
    }
    end = time(NULL);
    sub_duration = difftime(end,start);
    total_duration += sub_duration;
}
```

dosth.h

```
   extern      time_t start;
   extern      time_t end;
   extern      time_t sub_duration;
   extern      time_t total_duration;
   dosomethingelse();
```

dosth.cpp

```
#include"dosth.h"    
dosomethingelse()
{
    if(somecondition)
    {
        end = time(NULL);
        sub_duration = difftime(end,start);
        total_duration += sub_duration;
        writesomethingTofile();
        start = time(NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting in some printf() statements, or tracing through in a debugger, to see where you first got an unexpected value?

Comment: @TonyDelroy: yes i have traced it. it losses it value on the first function call to **dosmethingelse()**. At the first line of this function start has lost its value.

Comment: it sounds like you're not seeing the same start variable... perhaps print out the address of start inside `main()` (i.e. `printf("start is at @%p\n", &start)`) and again inside dosth.cpp so you can compare. More generally, it's better to have one timing.h/.c pair with the header providing say `void start(); int elapsed_second_and_reset();` and all the `time_t` variables private to `timing.c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `start` and `end` are global... when you set them inside `dosomethingelse()`, you're re-setting the `start` for the whole program.

The solution is to keep a local timer inside `dosomethingelse()`, and subtract the time spent in that function from the total.

Answer (score 0):

« start » is changed into « main » and « dosomethingelse » functions.
 Why did you do that ?